# How to set multiple environment variables in a single line on Windows?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, jestjs

I'm working on a Node.js project and using [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) as the test framework.  This project runs on Windows as it happens, and I'm having a heck of a time setting more than one environment variable on the command line.

Here's the relevant line in `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
     "test": "SET NODE_ENV=test & SET DB_URI=postgresql://<database stuff>> & jest -t Suite1 --watch --verbose false"
  },
```

As can be seen above, I'm setting both a `NODE_ENV` and  `DB_URI` environment variable prior to running `jest` via `npm run test`.

My problem is the that `DB_URI` environment variable doesn't appear to be set when jest runs.  The error I get back from jest makes it obvious it can't find it.  I do know that the first, `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set ok, but am not sure what's wrong with the second one, did I get the syntax wrong somehow?  Is anyone with jest experience on Windows doing something similar to what I'm trying?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just make the following change:

Use &&, also you need to remove the white space before and after the "&&".

```
"scripts": {
     "test": "SET NODE_ENV=test&&SET DB_URI=postgresql://<database stuff>>&&jest -t Suite1 --watch --verbose false"
  },
```

Comment: Was looking for this so much ... thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to add [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env). It should be able to set multiple environment variables for Windows and POSIX

**`package.json`**

```
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test DB_URI=postgresql://<database stuff>> jest -t Suite1 --watch --verbose false"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the environment variables from powershell you can do like so:

```
cmd /K "set f=df & echo %f%"
```

The output will be "df"